# Resizing an element in a scrollable container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to resize `.shape` box which is in `.wrapper` container. The user should be able to resize the box from four corners of it.

For understanding purpose, I wrote a short self explaining code. Please have a look at it.. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/xzkby36n/19/). (*I kept the wrapper container scrolled to a bit by default*).

PS: The bottom-right resizer is working fine.

Explanation of what I tried:

I had already written the resize functionality considering the scroll to the page (*body element*) itself using `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` but now I am considering the scroll to a element (`.wrapper`), where `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` are not working because the scroll is to `.wrapper` instead of page(*body element*).

Here is the code:

```
$('.shape').find('[data-resize]').on('mousedown', resizeStart);
$('.wrapper').scrollTop(1200);
var g = {
    fixed: 30
};
// Start of resizing functions
function resizeStart(e) {
    resizeStart.self = $(this);
    $(window).on('mousemove', resizeShape);
    $(window).on('mouseup', resizeEnd);
}

function resizeShape(e) {
    var $resizer = resizeStart.self;
    var $shape = $resizer.parents('.shape');
    var op = $resizer.data('resize');
    var offset = $shape.offset();
    var width = $shape.width();
    var height = $shape.height();
    var offsetLeft = e.clientX;
    var offsetTop = e.clientY;

    if (op === "br") {
        $shape.css({
            'width': offsetLeft - offset.left,
                'height': offsetTop - offset.top
        });
    } else if (op === "tr") {
        var xHeight = height + ($shape.offset().top - e.pageY);
        var xTop = height === g.fixed ? $shape.offset().top : e.pageY;
        var xWidth = e.pageX - $shape.offset().left;
        $shape.css({
            'height': xHeight,
                'top': xTop,
                'width': xWidth
        });
    } else if (op === "tl") {
        $shape.css({
            'height': height + (offset.top - offsetTop),
                'top': height === g.fixed ? offset.top : offsetTop,
                'width': width + (offset.left - offsetLeft),
                'left': width === g.fixed ? offset.left : offsetLeft,
        });
    } else if (op === "bl") {
        $shape.css({
            'width': width + (offset.left - offsetLeft),
                'left': width === g.fixed ? offset.left : offsetLeft,
                'height': offsetTop - offset.top
        });
    }
}

function resizeEnd(e) {
    $(window).off('mousemove');
    $(window).off('mouseup');
    resizeStart.self = null;
}
```

Comment: Is utilizing jquery-ui resizable http://jqueryui.com/resizable/ an option ?, e.g., `$( ".selector" ).resizable({
  containment: "parent"
});`

Comment: will do that if this take lot of time to fix. now in my time I can afford to learn this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is around the calculation of `top` and `left`.  In these cases you need to deal with the fact that your elements are positioned in relation to the scrollable box and not the overall page.

```
} else if (op === "tr") {
    var xHeight = height + ($shape.offset().top - e.pageY);
    var xTop = height === g.fixed ? $shape.offset().top : e.pageY;
    var xWidth = e.pageX - $shape.offset().left;
    $shape.css({
        'height': xHeight,
            'top': xTop - $(".wrapper").offset().top + $('.wrapper').scrollTop(),
            'width': xWidth
    });
}
```

The bit I added here is:

```
- $(".wrapper").offset().top + $('.wrapper').scrollTop()
```

Your cursor position is in relation to the overall page, so you need to translate that into the scrolling div.

Here is a fiddle with the "tr" updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/xzkby36n/20/

A similar approach should work for all `top` and `left` calculations.

Comment: This is working in fiddle but not in my project. I will work on that soon and let you know. Till then +1.  Thanks for this answer :)

Comment: This was misbehaving in my project because the `.wrapper` class has a stupid border of `1px` to it. See how it is behaving.. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/xzkby36n/25/). Any idea what could I do here? I tried adding `+1` or `-1` everywhere but no use.

Comment: Anyway,  I solved it.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/xzkby36n/26/). I just used some random which worked.. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green It seems like a simple `- 1` works fine.  The only jitter I see is around your check for `fixed` (which I honestly don't understand).

Comment: It is just to restrict the user to resize further.. I am working on how to stop the resize when height or width reaches the given `fixed` value i.e 30, which I defined on top of the code (_as g.fixed_).. and yeah simple -1 is working fine.

Comment: Here is the complete solution. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/xzkby36n/27/). Still working in fiddle but not in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var handles = {}; // resize handles
$.each(["se", "ne", "nw", "sw"], function(i, handle) {
    var elem = $("div[class^=area]").eq(i)
    elem.addClass("ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-" + handle).show(0);
     handles[handle] = elem[0];
  });
$(".shape").resizable({
    handles:handles,
    containment:"parent"
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xzkby36n/23/

See [Resizable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/)

Comment: Thanks will check this I I use jquery UI. just informing, the upper two resizalble are not working properly. :)

Comment: The top handles are backwards.